# Nginx rewrite rule with proxy pass

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I'm trying to implement nginx rewrite rules for the following situation

Request:

```
http://192.168.64.76/Shep.ElicenseWeb/Public/OutputDocuments.ashx?uinz=12009718&iinbin=860610350635
```

Should be redirected to:

```
http://localhost:82/Public/OutputDocuments.ashx?uinz=12009718&iinbin=860610350635
```

I tried this with no luck:

```
location /Shep.ElicenseWeb/ {
    rewrite ^/Shep.ElicenseWeb/ /$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:82;
}
```

What is the correct way to perform such a rewrite for nginx ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your rewrite statement is wrong.

The $1 on the right refers to a group (indicated by paratheses) in the matching section.

Try:

```
rewrite  ^/Shep.ElicenseWeb/(.*)  /$1 break;
```

Comment: you can try it: 
>       location / {
     rewrite ^/(.*) /Shep.ElicenseWeb/$1 break;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
    }

Answer (score 9):

You're missing a trailing slash:

```
location /Shep.ElicenseWeb/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:82/;
}
```

This will work without a rewrite.