# Remove .jsp ending with tomcat and nginx

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I would like to `www.example.com/test.jsp` as `www.example.com/test`.

URL rewriting and so on should be too slow. Are there any alternatives? For example, maybe using the jsp files or only servlets when they work with java?

I'm looking for good solution in terms of performance and for the google ranking. The website has 200 pages and grows, so I can't do it manually for every page.

I googled but I didn't find a good answer.

Comment: Actually, *big players* have enough of junior developers to do it manually ;)

Comment: *" I can't do it manually for every page"* -> This is why you script this sort of stuff :-) You can just create a script that generates these pages, and you run this every time you add a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe you wrote a website with 200+ separate jsp pages. Consider changing site architecture, for example if you have online store with many pages of the same type, you could write only one jsp content page as template and use [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) architecture to build real page content.

Comment: Cant do it, nearly every page has its own layout and need to be indexed. But at least I have a team.

Answer (score 0):

In the nginx configuration, you can make a rewrite of the url when you do the proxy pass

Comment: Jeah I use proxy pass, caching and load balancing to pass to some different servers. How to do this? Didnt find a working example for me.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539246/nginx-rewrite-rule-with-proxy-pass

Comment: This is more of a comment, or best if the questions are duplicates, use the flag option to do so, than an answer.